# Using Xcode Instruments to print objects from memory address

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

Is it possible to get more meaningful information on a leaking object in instruments? At the moment Instruments will tell me the type (`NSArray`) and the memory address (`0x123456`). Normally if I was debugging with LLDB I'd do a `po 0x123456` to get a bit more info on the instance of the object. Is there any equivalent in Instruments, or am I approaching this in the wrong way? Any advice would very welcome!

Comment: Aren't you able to see the call stack where the leak occurs (the right-hand pane)?

Comment: @trojanfoe, What does the stack trace have to do with the object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the leaks, call tree you can see all the leaks you have, double clicking on any of them will show you the segment of code that is producing it, it also adds a percentage on the line it thinks its doing the leak

Also you can add NSLogs in your code and in instruments navigate to console view to see the logs

Comment: Where is the "console view"?